# C++ equivalent to taking address of a constant?

Tags: c++, g++

I've got some code written in C (specifically targeted to gcc) that needs to also compile as C++ (g++).  I've run into a construct I'm having difficulty dealing with.

There are some macros used in a lot of places which basically take the address of a constant, although they also work on non-constants.  The construct winds up looking something like this:

```
int *iptr = (&(int){5});
```

What this essentially lets happen is a constant be specified, and then a pointer to that constant can be taken for use in a function that requires an int pointer, but only a constant is specified.  Multiple values can also be specified inside the curley braces to construct an actual temporary array, too. And it works great.

Problem in, g++ does not like this at all, throwing

```
error: non-lvalue in unary `&'
```

Update: Looks like I can take the address of a constant in C++ by doing something like:

```
const int & ref = 5;
```

So that's the starting point for the direction I'm trying to take.

Comment: C++ allows const references to bind to rvalues.

Comment: What do you expect to use with the address of a *literal*? First off, a constant is not an object, so it need not even have an address, which is the reason you are getting that error. Still I am trying to figure out what you would do with the address if you could... [Note: there is a difference between a constant and a literal, a constant *is* an object `const int five=5; const int* p = &five;` is ok. But a literal is a value]

Comment: @Ben: Looks like I can use `const int & ref = 5;` but I can't use `const int & ref = { 5,6,7 };` which is also a possibility.

Comment: @David: This is used to implement collections on arbitrary data types.  I could do something like `Push(array,5)` and the the macros would ultimately reduce it to a four byte memcopy.  If the data is a struct, I wind up needing to do something like `Push(array,{field1,field2})`.

Comment: @thang: can you give an example of using []?

Comment: @Michael: Decide whether you want C or C++, in C++ you would not use macros in general post your concern and you will get proposed solutions (including but not limited to constructors) Also note that the compiler is probably smart enough to optimize your code further than what you can do with your macros. For example, you might be surprised that the `memcpy` in your code actually gets discarded by the compiler and substituted by a couple of load/store operations. The cost of a function call is quite high compared to copying a few bytes.

Comment: I'd suggest making _another_ macro that works on constants (literals?). That will be a lot easier to read in six months, and will also have a better chance of working in C++.

Comment: @Seth I'm open to suggestions on what that macro would look like

Comment: What does the original one look like?

Comment: Why does that code compile with C?

Comment: With the code you've written so far, I'm not sure why it wouldn't just be `int iptr[] = {5};`

Comment: @Seth: `#define A(type,x) (&(type){x})`

Comment: So is your problem that you have code which is doing something like `f(A(int,{1,2,3}))`, and you are trying to come up with a C++-compatible macro `A` that will let that code work?

Comment: @Vaughn: yes, that's correct.  Or `f(A(int,{1}))`

Comment: I'm not sure how that macro was working for multiple values.  The preprocessor would see the commas and treat them as separate arguments.

Comment: In the case of multiple values I have a second preprocessor macro, `#define Of(...) __VA_ARGS__`.  So it would actually be `f(A(int,Of(1,2,3)))`.

Comment: And just for completeness, there is a third macro, `#define Arr(...) {__VA_ARGS__ }` in case the arguments is an actual array.

Comment: @David: The code needs to work with both C and C++, although of course for the definitions it's perfectly acceptable to define it one way or the other depending on which language is in use.  Also regarding memcpy being optimized to a load/store in some cases, that is exactly what is expected.

Comment: @Michael: My point is that `memcpy` is an expensive operation, and you are creating a framework to ensure that it is called only to have the compiler remove that away, a futile exercise, if you ask me. For a few integers, plain assignment is going to be more efficient than `memcpy` (the compiler could not optimize your call, and then your `memcpy` ends up being much more expensive than the plain assignments...). You are going out of your way to *pessimize* code with the hope that the compiler will *optimize* it back to something simpler...

Comment: @David: the argument isn't always an integer.  it could be something like `struct x { int a; float b; };` with `Push(array,{5,1.6})` (macro expanded) (where array is an array of struct x); there's a hidden size field in the array structure that gets passed to memcpy.

Comment: @David: I've come to the conclusion that your answer regarding choosing either C or C++ is the correct one.  C and C++ are too different and linking C++ code to code compiled as straight C is simple enough.  If you want to submit that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to work in both C and C++, although it only compiles under C++11, not C++03.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define A(type,x) (&(const type &)(type)x)
#define Of(...) { __VA_ARGS__ }
#else
#define A(type,x) (&(type){x})
#define Of(...) __VA_ARGS__
#endif
```

Test Code:

```
int test(const void *ptr,int len) {
  char *str = (char *)ptr;
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
    printf("%02X ",str[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}


int main() {
  test(A(int,5),4);
  test(A(x,Of(5,6)),8);

  int i=1,j=2;
  test(A(x,Of(i,j)),8);
}
```

Edit: Whoops, not quite there.  Doesn't work if the type is a pointer!

```
test(A(char *,9),4);
```

=>

```
error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type 'char*' to type 'const char*&'
```

Note: I'm abandoning this approach in favor of a different approach (compiling C code as C and linking it via C++) but will keep this answer up in case it is useful to somebody.